# Cookies become null when page is loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two asp.net pages. I set cookies using following code in Login Page.

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("sample");
cookie.Values.Add(cookieValues);
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Cookie is set successfully with expired date. I can see it on Watch window of Visual Studio.

However, when I tried to look for the values in another page during page load, both request and response cookies are null.

```
        HttpCookie respCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["sample"];
        if (respCookie != null)
        {
            DateTime expDate = respCookie.Expires;
            if (expDate > DateTime.Now)
                return respCookie;
            else
                return null;
        }
        else
            return null;
```

Comment: Are you using webforms ?

Comment: @SaadSuri

Yes I am. I am using ASP.NET web forms

Comment: Have you checked the existence of a Cookie with the Response keyword instead of Request? `Response.Cookies["cookie_name"]`

Comment: Same. Object is nullified

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling browser extensions or running your page in anonymous mode.

I was using Avast browser extension which messed with my cookies, worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).